# What would happen if I took my professor's accusation of cheating to court?

Tags: university, cheating

I was caught cheating during an university exam. The professor promptly failed me for the class. If I decided to take this issue to court, claiming that the professor has no evidence of my cheating, could I get away with it? At the time, there were no cameras in the room, and the professor did not take a video or photo of my cheating. In this scenario, who has the greater power, the student or the university?

Comment: In what country? You know that legal systems are different in different countries, right? This could even depend on the specific university's regulations. Anyway, you seem to be under the impression that "witness" is not a concept and that only video evidence is valid... How do you think justice worked before video cameras existed?

Comment: Suppose a burglar is caught picking a lock. The policeman promptly cuffs him. If a burglar decides to take this issue to court, claiming that policeman has no evidence of his cheating, could he get away with it?

Comment: The regulations / policies of the iniversity may state something along the lines of « evidence of cheating - based on eye-witness accounts - can lead to a grade of zero for that assessment or course until it has been discussed at the exam board ». « Students may be able to submit a letter of appeal to the board, which will be heard. » As students sign acceptance of the institutions policies and regulations they may have to accept the decision of the exam board.

Comment: @SolarMike Nothing technically stops it from going to court, probably.  In the US you can always try to take these things to court (Tom Brady had a similar agreement with the NFL, for example; still went to court). But the court is unlikely to bother with it for long if the judge isn't convinced that the plaintiff has a reasonable shot at proving that a law or the contractual terms and procedures were violated. Arbitration results that are "wrong" are often upheld because procedures and terms were adhered to. Courts are too overloaded to risk all arbitration cases falling to them.

Comment: Yes, in some countries you could due someone for farting while standing next to you... But the point about correct procedures is good.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: generally (in the UK at least) you cannot appeal either court judgements or arbitration on grounds of factual error, unless you can show that new evidence has come to light. This isn't about courts being overloaded and not wanting the work, it's the way the legal system works.

Comment: @WanderingChemist Yeah, that's pretty much what I said.  And I'd say it's about both.  Arbitration didn't exist in a functional fashion in the US until the 20's, and has only expanded to the "if you've looked at a box of Rice Krispies, then you must go to arbitration if you ever try to sue Kellogg's" state of today by a number of expansive rulings by the Supreme Court and the practical inability for an already underfunded and overloaded judicial system to resolve these disputes themselves.

Comment: If somebody saw you cheating and is willing to say so, that *is* evidence. Photos and videos are not the only form of "evidence".

Answer (score 8):

While the details of the answer depend on the particulars of the university and the country, in general I expect that a student would not be able to get very far with such a case.

The basic problem is that an accusation of cheating and an administrative sanction within the policies of the university is not generally a matter of law, and thus there is no reason that a court should be interested in involving itself. The student would thus have to find some sort of basis for claiming that some law is actually being broken (e.g., discrimination, defamation) or that a contract is being violated (not likely). One can imagine cases in which this is actually upheld (e.g., a professor who systematically blatantly overlooks cheating by white students while carefully monitoring black students), but in the case of a basically reasonable professor who caught a student cheating, it seems unlikely that the student would get very far in any reasonable courtroom.

In short: a guilty but litigious student might be able to cause a lot of annoyance and expense for a professor and a university, but would be unlikely to receive satisfaction in court.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi There are almost always still going to be many levels of university policy to go through before one could get to the point of actually making it a legal issue, since the university will have procedures for dealing with potential code violations, appeals procedures, disciplinary and review procedures, etc. And even then there may be questions of whether it actually counts as an enforceable contract. That doesn't stop you from trying to sue, but it does mean that you will likely lose, and might even get slapped with penalties for frivolous suit (depending on jurisdiction).

Comment: “The basic problem is that an accusation of cheating and an administrative sanction within the policies of the university is not generally a matter of law.“ - well in Germany at least that would be a violation of the Grundgesetz (the basic human rights or sth like that). Many university teachers think they are law, but no, this is just wrong.

Comment: @DonQuiKong Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @jakebeal administrative “sanctions“ (or whatever) are “Verwaltungsakte“ (disclaimer: there's still some discussion if single grades are, but grades for a complete course are) which means they are treated the same legally as if any other state office took some action (like your tax return) and can be taken to court equivalently. One of the basic laws here is freedom to choose your profession. Grading without probable explanation or reason or discriminatory would therefore be against that. (I don't know the equivalent English terms to make this sound more precise)

Comment: @DonQuiKong The question is not about grading without a reason, but is about whether a student could use legal means to avoid normal punishment for cheating.

Comment: @jakebeal reason = prove.

Comment: Looking at the actual code on cheating from a German university, I find that it says a student who cheats on an exam may be marked "insufficient" (which sounds equivalent to failing, in context). If the student wishes to dispute, the university considers the case and provides a written statement of reasons within two weeks. No legal proof required, just reasonable execution of internal procedure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75089/discussion-between-jakebeal-and-donquikong).

Answer (score 3):

This, independent of the law, sounds like a fast way to make enemies. You will make enemies with the Professor for taking them to court, the University for taking their staff to court and by-passing internal regulations (that could have punished potential misconduct by themselves!), some students and who knows! (recall that academics have rather big professional networks!)

It might sound like a good idea to 'enact justice', but there are a lot of 'problems' in academia that can best be solved from within academia.

So, don't sue your profs unless there are no other alternatives ('not suing' is often a reasonable alternative)